# arm-none-eabi-ld malloc undefined reference

Tags: c, malloc, microcontroller, texas-instruments, cortex-m

I'm working on some code for Texas Instruments' Tiva C Series TMC123G Launchpad (an ARM Cortex M4 MCU board), my code doesn't compile due to a `undefined reference to 'malloc'`.
startup_gcc.c and project.ld are part of [TivaWare](http://software-dl.ti.com/tiva-c/SW-TM4C/latest/index_FDS.html). Equivalent files can be found [here:](https://github.com/uctools/tiva-template)

- /src/startup_gcc.c
- /TM4C123GH6PM.ld

Here my console output when building:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o build/minimal.o src/minimal.c -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -DPART_TM4C123GH6PM -c -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1 -Dgcc -DF_CPU=80000000L -Isrc -Ilibraries -I/home/jakob/opt/tivaware
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o build/startup_gcc.o /home/jakob/opt/tivaware/examples/project/startup_gcc.c -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -DPART_TM4C123GH6PM -c -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1 -Dgcc - DF_CPU=80000000L -Isrc -Ilibraries -I/home/jakob/opt/tivaware
arm-none-eabi-ld -o build/a.out build/minimal.o build/startup_gcc.o -T /home/jakob/opt/tivaware/examples/project/project.ld --entry ResetISR --gc-sections
build/minimal.o: In function `Struct_begin':
/home/jakob/TivaMallocProblemMini/src/minimal.c:29: undefined reference to `malloc'
Makefile:66: recipe for target 'build/a.out' failed
make: *** [build/a.out] Error 1
```

Here is a minimal example of the problem, <strike>the `malloc` in the `main` function does not seem to cause any problems, only the one in the `Struct_begin` function.</strike> (It was optimized away.)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_Struct
{
    int16_t param;
} Struct;

Struct* Struct_begin(int16_t param);

int main() {
    Struct* s;

    s = malloc(sizeof(Struct));
    free(s);

    s = Struct_begin(10);
    s->param=0;

    for(;;);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Struct* Struct_begin(int16_t param) {
    Struct* s;

    s = malloc(sizeof(Struct));
    s->param = param;

    return s;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dwelch67/tivac_launchpad has some bare metal examples for the tiva c launchpads.  Not sure what problem you are really trying to solve here (why would you ever malloc on a microcontroller) but these very simple examples provide makefiles and such to get a working binary for these microcontrollers.

Comment: Is there a better way to get a pointer on a struct, always happy to learn more.

Comment: just declare the struct not a pointer to it, this is embedded bare metal code not an operating system

Comment: Struct my_struct;  //done, allocated

Comment: Oh, that would make it a easier.

Comment: or you could do some sort of *mystruct definition then in the code mystruct=(Struct *)0x1234500; and pick the address you want it at or a number of other things, but simply declaring it and depending on global or local it is automatically allocated from .data or the stack, no mallocs

Answer (score 3):

You are working on an embedded platform. In these circumstances, GCC (or rather ld) may not automatically link to a standard C library. You might need to explicitly need to link to the platform's standard library or you might need to supply your own implementation of malloc.

Comment: that is in part what newlib is about, a C library that is easy to port to whatever, there are a couple of backend files libc_func.c and another one in the same directory, which you port to your environment.  It is super easy for starting out to just go through and make all the functions return success, and then you can implement an inefficient but functional malloc (sbrk) by starting with a heap base you define and just keep adding to it and returning that as the address...